# How to Click on a WebElement present on any page of WebTable Using Selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium

**Hello Guys, I am trying to Click on a WebElement(CheckBox) which is present on Every Page of Webtable(i.e Pagination of WebTable) but I want to click on that Perticular Checkbox  which is passed through Xpath.**

**Below is the Code I have Tried**

```
HTML:

<form id="vContactsForm" action="https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm" method="post">
<table class="datacard" width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2" border="0">
    <tbody><tr><td class="datacardtitle" colspan="8" valign="top" align="left">
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr><td class="datacardtitle" valign="top" align="left">

        Contacts
        </td>
        <td class="datacardtitle" valign="top" align="right">

            <input class="button" value="Export" onclick="exportResultSet('query_slct_contacts_full');" type="button"> |
            <input class="button" value="Shortlist All Results" onclick="flagResultSet('query_slct_contacts_full', 'CONTACT', this);" type="button"> |
            <input class="button" value="New Contact" onclick="go('https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm?action=contact&amp;sub=load&amp;client_id=&amp;edit=1');" type="button">
        </td></tr></tbody></table>

        </td></tr>

        <tr><td colspan="7" valign="top" align="left">
            <div class="pagination">Pages : <strong>1</strong> | <a 
href="https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm? 
sr=21&amp;action=contact&amp;sub=start&amp;fl=&amp;">2</a> | <a 
href="https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm? 
sr=41&amp;action=contact&amp;sub=start&amp;fl=&amp;">3</a> | <a 
href="https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm? 
sr=61&amp;action=contact&amp;sub=start&amp;fl=&amp;">4</a> | <a 
href="https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm? 
sr=81&amp;action=contact&amp;sub=start&amp;fl=&amp;">5</a> | <a 
href="https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm? 
sr=101&amp;action=contact&amp;sub=start&amp;fl=&amp;">6</a> | <a 
href="https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm? 
sr=121&amp;action=contact&amp;sub=start&amp;fl=&amp;">7</a> | <a 
href="https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm? 
sr=141&amp;action=contact&amp;sub=start&amp;fl=&amp;">8</a> | </div> 
        </td>
            <td valign="top" align="right">


Java Code:

public class ClickOnAnyPageLink {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//All_Drivers//chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://freecrm.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("*****");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("*****");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Login']")).click();
    driver.switchTo().frame("mainpanel");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Contacts')]")).click();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    List<WebElement> all_pages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@id='vContactsForm']/descendant::div[1]/a"));

    System.out.println(all_pages.size());//7

    Iterator<WebElement> pageiterator = all_pages.iterator();

    while(pageiterator.hasNext())
    {
        WebElement elem = pageiterator.next();
        elem.click();// on second page
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        WebElement elem1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'nnn jhjhjk')]/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*/child::*"));

        if(elem1.isDisplayed())
        {
            elem1.click();  
            break;
        }

    }

    driver.close();
}

}
```

**But the issue i am facing here is `Element not found Exception`. Because Page is just clicked Once, It not iterating for every page of WebTable and Checking the presence of that Perticular Checkbox.**

**Exception Occurred for this xpath:** `//a[contains(text(),'nnn jhjhjk')]/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*/child::*`

**I didn't Understand what i am missing here, Hope I am Clear.Any help Would be appreciated. Thanks**

Comment: can you add a sample of your web page also

Comment: please keep the html of that element

Comment: @Ab123, Are you coming back to the previous page where your pagination elements are or the links are available on the pages that you land on after clicking `elem.click()` ? To me it looks like you click once, get on the next page and then doesn't do `driver.navigate().back();`. Is it or something else?

Comment: @NuOneTAttygalle,@bhupathi turaga, HTML Added

Comment: @eduPeeth I am Not coming back to Previous Page, I am just Chekcing the presences of WebElement on Next page, If Element found on First page Then Clicked on it else navigate to next Page. Hope I clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> all_pages = 
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@id='vContactsForm']/descendant::div[1]/a"));

    int sizeosallpages = all_pages.size();

    for(int i=2;i<=sizeosallpages;i++)
    {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='vContactsForm']/descendant::div[1]/a["+i+"]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);



        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("nnn jhjhjk"))
        {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'nnn jhjhjk')]/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*/child::*")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            break;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try changing the if loop to the following and let me know if it works for you or not -

```
List<WebElement> elem1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'nnn jhjhjk')]/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*/child::*"));

        if(elem1.size()>0)
        {
            elem1.click();  
            break;
        }
```

This is assuming you only get one element. Please let me know if it works.